# How can I create multiple loops in BigQuery SQL?

Tags: sql, loops, google-bigquery

I have a table that looks like this:

[image]

ClickScore0 means that this is the Click score for **current** month. ClickScore1 is the Click score for **previous** month, ClickScore2 for **2 months ago**, etc.

What I want to end up with is the following:

[image]

I have tried to create a loop, that for each user row, get the information for each ScoreType into new rows with the correct month and value. This is what I have, but it doesn't work.

```
WHILE Leads.ClickScore0 > 0 DO
    SELECT
        Leads.UserID,
        'Click' AS ScoreType, 
        DATE_TRUNC(DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 0 MONTH), MONTH) AS Month,
        Leads.ClickScore0 AS  Value
    FROM Leads;
END WHILE;

WHILE Leads.ClickScore1 > 0 DO
    SELECT
        Leads.UserID,
        'Click' AS ScoreType, 
        DATE_TRUNC(DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL -1 MONTH), MONTH) AS Month,
        Leads.ClickScore1 AS  Value
    FROM Leads;
END WHILE;
```

Updated:

The solution from @mikhail-berlyant seems to work, but I still don't get the month.
I also want to remove the "mir" part of the scoretype.
I have this:

```
select id, 
  regexp_extract(col, r'(.+)score') ScoreType, 
  date_sub(date_trunc(current_date(), month) , interval cast(regexp_extract(col, r'score(\d+)') as int64) month) Month, 
  cast(val as int64) Value
from (
  select t.id, x[offset(0)] col, x[offset(1)] val
  from `leads_20210127.leads` t,
  unnest(regexp_extract_all(to_json_string(t), r'"(?:miremailclick|miremailopen)\w+":\d+')) kv,
  unnest([struct(split(replace(kv, '"', ''), ':') as x)])
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below [BigQuery way of approaching your task]

```
select UserID, 
  regexp_extract(col, r'(.+)Score') ScoreType, 
  date_sub(date_trunc(current_date(), month) , interval cast(regexp_extract(col, r'Score(\d+)') as int64) month) Month, 
  cast(val as int64) Value
from (
  select UserID, x[offset(0)] col, x[offset(1)] val
  from `project.dataset.table` t,
  unnest(regexp_extract_all(to_json_string(t), r'"(?:Click|Open)\w+":\d+')) kv,
  unnest([struct(split(replace(kv, '"', ''), ':') as x)])
)
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Note: this exact code will work w/o any extra efforts/typing for any number of months and score types (in case if you have more than just two)

Comment: This solution seems to work, but I still don't get the month.
I also want to remove the "mir" part of the scoretype.
I have this:

select id, 
  regexp_extract(col, r'(.+)score') ScoreType, 
  date_sub(date_trunc(current_date(), month) , interval cast(regexp_extract(col, r'score(\d+)') as int64) month) Month, 
  cast(val as int64) Value
from (
  select t.id, x[offset(0)] col, x[offset(1)] val
  from `leads_20210127.leads` t,
  unnest(regexp_extract_all(to_json_string(t), r'"(?:miremailclick|miremailopen)\w+":\d+')) kv,
  unnest([struct(split(replace(kv, '"', ''), ':') as x)])
)

Answer (score 0):

You can unnest the values.  One common method in BigQuery uses arrays so the table can be scanned only once:

```
select t.userid, s.scoretype, s.score,
       date_add(date_trunc(current_date, month), interval n - 1 month) as month
from `table` t cross join
     unnest([struct(t.clickscore1 as score, 'click' as scoretype, 1 as n),
             struct(t.clickscore2 as score, 'click' as scoretype, 2 as n),
             struct(t.clickscore3 as score, 'click' as scoretype, 3 as n),
             struct(t.openscore1 as score, 'open' as scoretype, 1 as n),
             struct(t.openscore2 as score, 'open' as scoretype, 2 as n),
             struct(t.openscore3 as score, 'open' as scoretype, 3 as n)
            ]) s;
```

Comment: There seems to be a limit of 10 unnest statements. Is that correct? If so, this solution will be hard to implement due to a lot of score values.

Comment: @LeviH. . . . Not that I'm aware of.  In any case, there is just one `unnest()` in this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Mikhail Berlyants answer I now have a solution that almost works as intended.

What I have now is this:

```
select id, 
  regexp_extract(col, r'mir(.+)[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]score') ScoreType, 
  date_sub(date_trunc(current_date(), month) , interval cast(regexp_extract(col, r'(\d+)score') as int64) month) Month, 
  cast(val as int64) Value
from (
  select t.id, x[offset(0)] col, x[offset(1)] val
  from `leads_20210127.leads` t,
  unnest(regexp_extract_all(to_json_string(t), r'"(?:miremailopen|miremailclick|)\w+":\d+')) kv,
  unnest([struct(split(replace(kv, '"', ''), ':') as x)])
)
```

This give me the scoretype, the month and the value.

The only thing that dont seem to work correctly is when the month number is higher than 9. This number (like miremailopen23score) can be a number between 0 (current month) up to 24 (24 months ago).

Also, I don't understand the last part of the query above. It seems to work okey as it is, but then I'm not sure if it needs to be there. The scoretypes are the following:

- emaildelivered
- emailopen
- emailclick
- formfill
- webvisit
- webvisitsearch
- webvisitsocial
- videoclick
- webdownload
- webvisitsearchpaid
- webvisitsocialpaid

The fields from the start is like this pattern: mirwebvisit21score

Comment: I feel like you should at least vote up my answer - but also accept it - as it is fully answered your original question while your answer is just minor tweaks based on outside your question!! :o)

Comment: Sure! I have upvoted now. I still need to handle numbers from 10-24 to add it as the answer.

Comment: My answer perfectly handles 10-24 as well as 0-9. As I mentioned already - your initial question is answered. If you have issue with applying it to more conditions of your case  - please post the NEW question and we will help! Don't forget to provide all relevant [new] details that you might missed in this question :o)